# Powershell: Task scheduler schtasks fails to start

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I use schtasks in a powershell script to run a specific scheduled task on a remote server. The script is very simple:

```
$server = "myserver"
$task = "mytask"
schtasks /Run /S $server /TN $task
```

Everything works fine, until I decide to draw a line after running the task:

```
$server = "myserver"
$task = "mytask"
schtasks /Run /S $server /TN $task
for ($i=0 ; $i -lt 90 ; $i++) { write-host -NoNewline "-" }
write-host "-"
```

In that case, the script will run properply three times and then it will never run the task again, unless I run it from a new powershell window.

The result looks like:

```
PS C:\temp> .\runtask.ps1
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "mytask".
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\temp> .\runtask.ps1
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "mytask".
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\temp> .\runtask.ps1
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "mytask".
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\temp> .\runtask.ps1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\temp> .\runtask.ps1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\temp>
```

Some observations:
- The number of times the script runs properly depends on the number of dashes in the line.
- Whether the server and task exist does not matter. If they do not exist the error "The network path was not found" is displayed for three tries and then, on the next attempts, nothing but the line.
- schtasks actually does not run the task when nothing is displayed. The first thing the task does is to add an event in the Application Event Log. The event is created when a SUCCESS occurs. No event is created when schtasks displays nothing.

The question is: What can I do to make the script work properly any number of times while displaying lines of dashes?

Comment: What version of PowerShell?  I'm using 4.0 and I increased the number of hyphens to 900 and I'm not seeing any problems.

Comment: Version 2.0 on Windows 2008 R2 SP1. I know it's a shame but I have to deal with it.